# div container should be wrapped by image calculated dimensions

Tags: html, css, image

I change the original size of my image, but still would like div around it to wrap it tightly without 30% bottom-margin. **How can I do it?**

here is the code, in which the warpping div has a bottom left-over, that I'd like to get rid of:

```
<div style="background-color:blue">
  <img src="myImage.jpg" style="height:70%">
```

Comment: `style="height:70%"` means 70% of parent div height. So that behavior is natural. If you use absolute pixel values, you should be fine.

Comment: Use  `style="height:100%"` instead `70%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if that helps.

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" style="height:70%; display:block;">
```